# 「GET http://yourdomain/crossdomain.xml net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED」エラーを解消することが出来ません

Tags: javascript, html5, 動画

サイトを参考に下記ソースのようなvideo playerの実装中なのですが、
HTML表示時に「GET http://yourdomain/crossdomain.xml net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED」
というエラーがコンソールに出力されプレイヤーを実行することが出来ない状況です。

原因を調査すると、crossdomain.xmlの設定がされていないことのようだと思ったのですが、crossdomain.xmlが見当たりません。

分かる方がいましたらご教授をお願いします。

また、上記エラーを解消するcrossdomain.xmlの設定方法については[このサイト](https://support.brightcove.com/ja/video-cloud/%E3%82%B5%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%89%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A5%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88/flash-%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B9%E3%83%89%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3-%E3%82%BB%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A5%E3%83%AA%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3)を参考にしようと思うのですが、
宜しければcrossdomain.xmlの設定方法についてもご教授を頂けると助かります。

[実装の参考サイト(項目:Strobe Media Playback と OSMF 用 SS 動的プラグイン)](http://azure.microsoft.com/ja-jp/documentation/articles/media-services-use-osmf-smooth-streaming-client-plugin/)

```js
<body>
// OFMF player
    <object width="200" height="50">
        <param name="movie" value="http:/省略/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf"></param>
        <param name="flashvars" value="src=http:省略/Manifest&autoPlay=true&plugin_AdaptiveStreamingPlugin=http://yourdomain/MSAdaptiveStreamingPlugin-v1.0.3-osmf2.0.swf&AdaptiveStreamingPlugin_retryLive=true&AdaptiveStreamingPlugin_retryInterval=10"></param>
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false"></param>
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
        <param name="enableStageVideo" value="false"></param>
        <param name="wmode" value="direct"></param>
        <embed src="http:/省略/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf"
               type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
               allowscriptaccess="always"
               allowfullscreen="false"
               wmode="direct"
               flashvars="src=http:省略Manifest&autoPlay=true&plugin_AdaptiveStreamingPlugin=http://yourdomain/MSAdaptiveStreamingPlugin-v1.0.3-osmf2.0.swf&AdaptiveStreamingPlugin_retryLive=true&AdaptiveStreamingPlugin_retryInterval=10">
        </embed>
    </object>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

「名前が解決できなかった」なので、ファイルではなく、ドメインが見つからない時に表示されますね。

> これには、"MSAdaptiveStreamingPlugin-v1.0.3-osmf2.0.swf" を Web サーバーにコピーし、次に示す手順を使用して HTTP 読み込みを行ってください。

とあるので、`http://yourdomain/MSAdaptiveStreamingPlugin-v1.0.3-osmf2.0.swf` はあなたの配置したサーバーに合わせて修正する必要があるのではないでしょうか。 `yourdomain` はよくプレースホルダとして使われます。

Comment: エラーを解消することが出来ました。ありがとうございます。
しかし、新たな問題が発生しましたので、別で質問することにします。